# correct pattern for matching two word with regex in .net

Tags: c#, .net, regex

i want to filter sentences that contains two specific word. i searched for suitable pattern and i got this :

```
/^(?=.*\bWord1\b)(?=.*\bWord2\b).*$/
```

but it doesnt work in .Net Regex.
whats the correct pattern for matching two word with regex in .net Regex class?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Error in your regex**

```
^(?=.\bWord1\b)(?=.\bWord1\b)
```

Your regex says that match a non word(`in start of the sentence due to ^`) and find the `Word1`. Same goes with `Word2`. So basically you are saying find both words after one letter from starting is seen.

```
^(non-word) <spaces only for clarity> Word1
  <------>                            <--->
First . of            and   ==>       Find
lookahead             then  ==>       Word1
matches this
<-------------->
As lookaheads are of zero width, the same thing will be applied for Word2. 
So, we are finding Word1 and Word2 both at same position which can't be possible.
Also your words can be anywhere in sentence and not just after first position.
```

**Corrected regex**

```
^(?=.*\bword1\b)(?=.*\bword2\b).*$
```

**[regexstorm demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%3F%3D.*%5Cbword1%5Cb)(%3F%3D.*%5Cbword2%5Cb).*%24&i=word1%20abcdkl%20word2)**

*Regex Breakdown*

```
^ #Starting of string
 (?=.*\bword1\b) #Lookahead to find word1 anywhere in the sentence
 (?=.*\bword2\b) #Lookahead to find word2 anywhere in the sentence
 .* #If both of above is true, then find the whole sentence
$ #End of string
```

*C# Code*

```
string input = "word1 abcdkl word2";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(?=.*\bword1\b)(?=.*\bword2\b).*$");

Match match = regex.Match(input);

if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[0].Value);   
}
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/QHzSp1)**

Comment: Regex filterReg = new Regex("^(?=.*\bjack\b)(?=.*\bjames\b).*$"); 
doesnt work

Comment: @Mehdi see the code..you need to use `@` before regex..or if you are not using, then double escape `\\b`

Comment: Good answers always explain WHY the code works compared to the original one.

Comment: how can regex expression be set to find few begining charachters of matching word irrespective of their posting , what i mean find in all the program where i have commented two 2 or more words but here seqlence may be diffrent or spelling may be mistached so i want few beginig charachters of each word or other wise i want to find two or more words which are on same line irrespective of  1st this then 2nd then thrid

Comment: @sushil.agarwal please post a new question with your requirements.